# Unable to click on images selector SELENIUM JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to click on png image and encounter error.

HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="i2uiSetMenuCoords(this,event)" href="javascript:showMenu('9721')"><img hspace="1" src="./skins/e2-modern/images/dropdown.png" border="0px"></a>
```

Code:

```
if (navigateToDetails)  {
            SearchListSelectorExt selector = new SearchListSelectorExt();
            //switchToFrame(getFrames(FRAME_TYPE.rcp_content));
            //switchToFrame(getHeaderFrames());
            WebElement element= selector.get(By.xpath("//a[contains(@src,'./skins/e2-modern/images/dropdown.png'"));
            Object value = selector.getElementValue(element);
            systemDocID = value.toString();

            selector.clickName(systemDocID);
            //selector.clickName(CustomerItem);
        }
```

Comment: Even your xpath is correct, just you have wrongly closed bracket:-                  /a[contains(@src,'./skins/e2-modern/images/dropdown.png')]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong...Use the below xpath

```
//a/img[contains(@src,'/skins/e2-modern/images/dropdown.png')]
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if it is not working

Comment: It's worth using a tool like Firebug (on FireFox and Chrome) to get xpaths, then you won't get errors like this hopefully :)

Comment: @Damon Ng Happy to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath:-

```
//img[contains(@src,'dropdown.png')]
```

- Here, we are directly looking for img tag such that its src attribute contains dropdown.png text.
- If there are more than 1 web elements satisfying above xpath, then try to make it unique by adding extra attributes or parent.

  //a/img[contains(@src,'dropdown.png')]

  //img[@hspace='1' and contains(@src,'dropdown.png')]

Comment: provide brief explanation of your answer. So everyone can understand properly